# Global @angular/cli version is 14 but running "ng new" is creating angular 12 project

Tags: angular, angular14

My global `@angular/cli` is 14.
Running `ng version` is returning:

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.1
Node: 16.17.0
Package Manager: npm 8.15.0 
OS: darwin x64
```

But when I create a new ng project using `ng new my-project` it creates it in Angular 12 (all @angular dependencies in the package.json are "~12.2.0").

#### What am I missing?

*This is after I removed the global `@angular/cli`, clearing npm cache and instaled `@angular/cli@14`